# Utilizar "FieldByName" ou a variável associada?

Tags: banco-de-dados, string, delphi, variáveis

Quando tenho um `ClientDataset`, uma `MemoryTable` ou uma `Query`, qual a diferença de eu pegar o valor de um campo utilizando `FieldByName()` ou a variável associada ao campo?

No exemplo abaixo, pego o último ID de um campo no banco e diferenciei os dois modos de pegar o valor da *query*:

```
fDm.fdqHistorico.Open;
iId := 0;

if fDm.fdqHistorico.RecordCount > 0 then
begin
  iId := fDm.fdqHistorico.FieldByName('his_id').AsInteger; // Modo 1
  iId := fDm.fdqHistoricohis_id.AsInteger;                 // Modo 2
end;

Inc(iId);
```

- Modo 1: FieldByName
- Modo 2: Variável associada

Tem alguma diferença de desempenho ou alguma outra coisa? Ou simplesmente é a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O modo 2 é mais rápido por ser resolvido em tempo de compilação e o compilador pode fazer verificação se o nome está correto.

O modo 1 tem a vantagem da flexibilidade, ainda que da forma usada não seja tão vantajoso, se usar uma variável no lugar do literal dá para ser criativo e permitir acessar os campos sem conhecê-los, dando a chance do usuário escolher o que quer por alguma expressão, etc. Também pode dar errado se não souber o que está fazendo, e ficar até inseguro.

Comment: Um adicional à resposta do @bigown: O FieldByName('his_id') só apresentará erro quando a aplicação 'rodar' já a associação da erro logo no desenvolvimento (se houver)!

Comment: Complementando, muitas pessoas falam que utilizando variável associada não funciona `debug` (não da pra ver o valor), para desencargo, testei agora e funciona da mesma forma. ;)

Comment: Exato, tanto no CTRL+F7 quanto passando o mouse por cima do tipo (AsInteger, AsFloat, AsString) etc...

Comment: O modo 2 também é mais rápido, além de todas as vantagens citadas pelo @bigown, por não precisar fazer uma busca na lista de campos da query/dataset.